# skipped xx frames [CAUSED BY FACEBOOK SDK]

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I m finding the root cause for application lag and skipped frame. In the end found out it is cause by Facebook SDK (everything). 
I tested following steps : 
I opened the activity for multiple times (OnResume) at everyscreen. And after (50) times around app begin lagging.

After i removed this line at minfest working fine.

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

```
// Facebook Core only (Analytics)
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.33.0'
// Facebook Login only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
// Facebook Share only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.33.0'
// Facebook Places only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.33.0'
// Facebook Messenger only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.33.0'
// Facebook App Links only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.33.0'
// Facebook Android SDK (everything)
//Dont import everything if you dont need. Low end device will lag
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
//dont use sdk 4.37 or +

Comment: Do you have a question as well? (Stackoverflow is Q&A site)

Comment: I would like clarify is it the root cause and Is there anyone out there facing same problem like me?